# How do subkernels return results to the master kernel?

Tags: parallelization, return-value

Assume you have a large Table defined in the master kernel. I want to compute its elements in parallel. I am familiar with `ParallelTable` but, for my particular case, the elements on one row depend on the values of the previous rows. So, I wrote a simple code to test how I could parallelize the evaluation of each row and modify the table created with the master kernel:

```
ClearAll[RMAX, myTable, i, r]

LaunchKernels[8];

RMAX = 16;

myTable = Table[If[i == 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, Floor[RMAX/2]}, {r, 1, RMAX}];

Print[TableForm[myTable]]; (* Just checking the table is correct *)

Attributes[myTable] (* I am getting messages saying that myTable is Protected which doesn't allow me to change its values in the subkernels *)

SetSharedVariable[RMAX, myTable, i];

For[i = 2, i <= Floor[RMAX/2], i++, 
  ParallelEvaluate[Unprotect[myTable]; 
   For[r = 2*i + 2, r <= RMAX, r++, myTable[[i]][[r]] = i]]]; (* I want to evaluate in parallel one row at a time only. I still get Symbol myTable in part assignment does not have an immediate value *)

Print[TableForm[myTable]]; (* The subkernels did not change any element of the table *)

CloseKernels[];
```

I can see the elements of `myTable` in the subkernels. I can operate on them. I just can't assign new values to each element of `myTable` from the subkernels.

How do you do this? Your help is appreciated.